# ncurses timeout() is terminating my program

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm receiving input in a timed loop, and getch() blocks (waits for key) the program even though the loop has ended. When utilizing timeout(), or other functions, it doesn't block, but terminates the entire program.

```
initscr();
raw();
noecho();

while(time(NULL)-initTime < maxtime)
{
    timeout(3); // 3 as an example
    getch();
}
// do stuff

refresh();
// hit a key to exit
getch();
endwin();
```

That seems not useful, so I must be missing something. How to non-block (e.g within 3 seconds), and continue executing my code?

Comment: The timeout value does not apply only to a single event. The timeout value will continue to apply until changed. Therefore, you can move the `timeout(3);` call to be just before the `while` loop. After the `while` loop, call `timeout(-1);` (or any negative value) to set blocking mode before calling `getch()` to wait for a key to exit.

Comment: @IanAbbott that’s right, and exactly what I eventually realized and did.

Answer (score 0):

As also stated in the comments, the problem is with setting `timeout` only once, and thus apply it to the whole program.

The solution:

```
while(time(NULL)-initTime < maxtime)
{
    timeout(3); // 3 as an example
    getch();
}
timeout(-1); // The rest of the getch() calls can block now
```